# How to add a table in a QGroupBox, PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qgroupbox

I'm pretty new to PyQt5 and still struggle. I tried the whole day adding rows and columns in a QGroupBox. The only solution I found was adding a QTableWidget, the problem with that is the widget size.

For now I only wanna have the header of this table, the user can then add rows to this table.
[ID, Name]

I want to have the cells, but not the 'window' that comes with it. If I try to align it in the center of the QGroupBox it aligns the whole thing in the center, not the columns. (the columns are in the top left corner of the widget, see picture)

[image: How it currently looks]

That's the code snippet which creates the table:

## Create the box

```
    self.groupbox1 = QGroupBox('Data')
    self.groupbox1.setMaximumWidth(350)
    self.groupbox1.setMaximumHeight(400)
    self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.groupbox1.setLayout(self.layout)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.groupbox1)
```

## Create a QTableWidget

```
    self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
    self.table_widget.setColumnCount(2)
    self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Data'])
    self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.table_widget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.table_widget.setMaximumSize(200, 200)
    self.upper_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    self.upper_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
```

The only thing I found was .resizeColumnsToContents and .setSectionResizeMode which is only adjusting the columns depending on what will be in there.

By setting the maximum size of the table widget I made it smaller but that's not quite what I want. If there is more data added to the table the user has to scroll because the widget isn't big enough.
Isn't there anything that is adjusting that automatically?

Or is there another solution to the problem? The button where the user can choose which data to be displayed (which row will be added) should be directly under the rows in the center and move automatically up/down if rows are deleted/added. This is also not possible if I have to have a fixed size of the QTableWidget.

Hope I explained it well enough. I'm thankful for every answer that could bring me closer to the solution. :)
(Yes, I had a look at all related posts on Stack Overflow already and probably every other page, didn't solve my problem unfortunately)

Comment: Sooner or later, the table will need to scroll. There is the possibility of making the table only show the header and dynamically alter its height, but most of the times that kind of approach results both tricky to properly implement and often discouraged if it alters the whole layout (the fact that the "add" button keeps moving is actually annoying to the user). The question is: what are you going to place in those cells? Because it seems like you're trying to use the QTableWidget for layout purposes, but there are rare cases for which that makes really sense.

Comment: The user can add 5 tabs maximum. I have a list with instances. From those instances I get the ID and the Name (which will be displayed in the table). When clicking on the button the user sees every available data, chooses one and then it should be displayed in the table as new row. [instance.id, instance.name]

Comment: Sorry but your comment is unclear; what do have tabs to do with the above?

Comment: sorry, I meant rows of course, not tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a modified version of Francesca Mazzeo answer.
It uses a subclassed `QTableWidget` with a reimplemented `resizeEvent()` method to get the "grow with added rows" behaviour.

There's one weird thing that I don't understand: Adding the first row doesn't trigger `resizeEvent()`. Subsequent rows do.

I'm posting this any way in the hope someone knows how to fix this.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView, QMessageBox


# class ExpandingTableWidget(QTableWidget):
#    def resizeEvent(self, event):
#        super().resizeEvent(event)
#        height = self.horizontalHeader().height()
#        row_count = self.verticalHeader().count()
#        for i in range(row_count):
#            height += self.verticalHeader().sectionSize(i)
#
#        self.setMaximumHeight(height + 2)


class TestApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Application')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)

        # Create a QVBoxLayout for the main window
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)  # 'self' refers to the main window
        self.groupbox1 = QGroupBox('Data')
        self.groupbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox1.setLayout(self.groupbox_layout)

        # Create a QTableWidget
        self.table_widget = ExpandingTableWidget()
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Name'])
        self.table_widget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.table_widget.setShowGrid(False)
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        # Create a QPushButton to add rows to the QTableWidget
        self.add_row_button = QPushButton('Add Row')
        self.add_row_button.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        # Add the QTableWidget and QPushButton to the QGroupBox layout
        self.groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget, stretch=1)
        self.groupbox_layout.addStretch(0)
        self.groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.add_row_button)

        # Add the QGroupBox to the main QVBoxLayout of the main window
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupbox1)

    def add_row(self):
        # Add a new row to the QTableWidget when the button is clicked
        row_position = self.table_widget.rowCount()
        self.table_widget.insertRow(row_position)
        self.table_widget.setItem(
            row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row_position + 1)))
        self.table_widget.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(''))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Edit:
New QTablewidget subclass using musicamente's comments:

```
class ExpandingTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model().rowsInserted.connect(self.set_height)
        self.model().columnsInserted.connect(self.set_height)

    def set_height(self):
        height = self.horizontalHeader().height() + self.verticalHeader().length() + self.frameWidth() * 2
        self.setMaximumHeight(height)
```

Comment: Changing size within a resize event should *always* be done with care, and is not always reliable (as this case shows). A more appropriate implementation should rely on functions and signals that actually change the viewport size. For instance, in this case by connecting to the model's `rowsInserted` and `columnsInserted` (the latter to ensure that the header is shown even when there are only columns set, but no row exists). Also: there's no need for iterating through the section sizes, just use the header `length()`. Finally, don't use an arbitrary value for the margin, but `frameWidth()`.

Comment: Will have a look at it, thanks! @musicamante when would you recommend to change events or override things? I still didn’t figure out the usage/purpose of that as nothing worked so far and it seems pretty complicated.

Comment: I just need it to adjust automatically such that the button can be directly under the last row

Comment: @musicamente, See edit. Setting the viewport size didn't give the desired result. It just changed the 'white area' inside the frame. The rest of your remarks were spot on as usual.

Comment: @Souleater, if you want the button to be directly under the tablewidget, just add the stretch after the button instead of before.

Comment: @mahkitah your code is making the window bigger, exactly how I want it, the only issue here is that I have fixed column sizes and that I don't see the first row when I click the button for the first time, always have to press twice. Then I see the first two rows. All the other rows afterwards are added as they should. Can I avoid this somehow?

Comment: @mahkitah Great, will try that with the button, thanks :) Edit: Worked perfectly!

Comment: @mahkitah Just seen your edit, haven't seen it. With this, I see the first row immediately after clicking on the button. Your answer got me where I wanted to be, thanks a lot!

Comment: @mahkitah I didn't mean that you need to change the viewport size, but to rely on the functions or signals that may change it.

Comment: @musicamente, ah okay, I misunderstood that. Are you happy with the new solution?

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView, QMessageBox


class TestApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Application')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)

        # Create a QVBoxLayout for the main window
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)  # 'self' refers to the main window
        self.groupbox1 = QGroupBox('Data')
        self.groupbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox1.setLayout(self.groupbox_layout)

        # Create a QTableWidget
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Name'])
        self.table_widget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.table_widget.setShowGrid(False)
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        # Create a QPushButton to add rows to the QTableWidget
        self.add_row_button = QPushButton('Add Row')
        self.add_row_button.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        # Add the QTableWidget and QPushButton to the QGroupBox layout
        self.groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.add_row_button)

        # Add the QGroupBox to the main QVBoxLayout of the main window
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupbox1)

    def add_row(self):
        # Add a new row to the QTableWidget when the button is clicked
        row_position = self.table_widget.rowCount()
        self.table_widget.insertRow(row_position)
        self.table_widget.setItem(
            row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row_position + 1)))
        self.table_widget.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(''))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Try this and adapt it to your project.

This is the output:

[image]

**version 2023-07-26 first code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView, QMessageBox


class TestApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Application')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)

        # Create a QVBoxLayout for the main window
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)  # 'self' refers to the main window
        self.groupbox1 = QGroupBox('Data')
        self.groupbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox1.setLayout(self.groupbox_layout)

        # Create a QTableWidget
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Name'])
        self.table_widget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.table_widget.setShowGrid(False)

        # Set a fixed width for the 'ID' column
        self.table_widget.setColumnWidth(0, 50)
        #Set a fixed width for the 'NAME' column
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        #Block widht fro the 'ID' column
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Fixed)

        # Create a QPushButton to add rows to the QTableWidget
        self.add_row_button = QPushButton('Add Row')
        self.add_row_button.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        # Add the QTableWidget and QPushButton to the QGroupBox layout
        self.groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.add_row_button)

        # Add the QGroupBox to the main QVBoxLayout of the main window
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupbox1)

    def add_row(self):
        # Add a new row to the QTableWidget when the button is clicked
        row_position = self.table_widget.rowCount()
        self.table_widget.insertRow(row_position)
        self.table_widget.setItem(
            row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row_position + 1)))
        self.table_widget.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(''))

        # Resize the 'Name' column to fit the contents
        self.table_widget.resizeColumnToContents(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Try this, I have resized and blocked the auto resize for the ID necklace and for the NAME column it resizes automatically

This is the output:

[image]

**version 2023-07-26 second code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView, QScrollArea, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TestApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Application')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)

        # Create a QVBoxLayout for the main window
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)  # 'self' refers to the main window

        # Create a QScrollArea and set it as the main widget
        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        # Create a QWidget to hold the content
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)

        # Create a QGroupBox to display the table
        self.groupbox1 = QGroupBox('Data')
        self.groupbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox1.setLayout(self.groupbox_layout)
        self.groupbox1.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, False)
        self.groupbox1.hide()  # Hide the group box initially

        # Create a QTableWidget
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Name'])
        self.table_widget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.table_widget.setShowGrid(False)
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        # Add the QTableWidget to the QGroupBox layout
        self.groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)

        # Add the QGroupBox to the main_layout of the main_widget
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.groupbox1)

        # Create a QPushButton to add rows to the QTableWidget
        self.add_row_button = QPushButton('Add Row')
        self.add_row_button.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        # Add the QPushButton to the main_layout of the main_widget
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.add_row_button)

        # Set the main_widget as the widget for the QScrollArea
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.main_widget)

        # Set the QScrollArea to expand the widget vertically
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.main_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        # Set the number of rows to display (2 rows in this case)
        self.displayed_rows = 1

        # Calculate and set the initial height of the QScrollArea based on the QTableWidget height
        table_height = self.table_widget.rowHeight(0) * self.displayed_rows + self.groupbox_layout.spacing()
        self.scroll_area.setMinimumHeight(table_height)

        # Set the maximum height for the QGroupBox
        self.groupbox1.setMaximumHeight(table_height)

    def add_row(self):
        if not self.groupbox1.isVisible():  # Show the group box when the first row is added
            self.groupbox1.show()

        # Add a new row to the QTableWidget when the button is clicked
        row_position = self.table_widget.rowCount()
        self.table_widget.insertRow(row_position)
        self.table_widget.setItem(row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row_position + 1)))
        self.table_widget.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(''))
 
        # Recalculate the new height of the QGroupBox based on the updated QTableWidget height
        table_height = self.table_widget.rowHeight(
            0) * (self.displayed_rows + 1.5) + self.groupbox_layout.spacing()
        self.groupbox1.setFixedHeight(table_height)
        self.table_widget.setMinimumHeight(table_height)

        if (self.displayed_rows < 5):
            self.displayed_rows += 1
        else:
            # Enable scrolling when the displayed rows reach 5
            self.update_scroll_area_height()

    def update_scroll_area_height(self):
        table_height = self.table_widget.rowHeight(
            0) * (self.displayed_rows + 2) + self.groupbox_layout.spacing()
        self.groupbox1.setFixedHeight(table_height)
        self.scroll_area.setMinimumHeight(table_height)

        # Enable vertical scrolling
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Try this and adapt it to your project.

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! Is it possible to adjust the widget such that it ‘grows’ when adding a row? I mean to only see the header and when adding a row, the widget gets bigger. I’m already happy with this solution though, can build on that :)

Comment: I think I’ve developed the code you need, but the code is great for the comments section, if you share me an email I’ll send you the code... Or you can contact me on my contact form (Contact Section) or on my social networks (Footer) that you can find on my website https://devfrancescamazzeo.com/

Comment: @FrancescaMazzeo Please note that if a solution may respect the requests of a question, you should consider [edit]ing your post to improve your answer (or even create a new one). Private communication is not frown upon, but if any addition to an existing post is consistent with the request of the OP, it's preferable to do it publicly, as it may be helpful to others that may face similar problems (which is the primary purpose of SO).

Comment: Edited, sorry I didn't know posts with green checkmarks could be edited

Comment: Thank you for this edit but I actually don’t need to scroll, the user is able to add only 5 rows maximum anyways. The space in the QGroupBox should be fine. It should be visually ‘attractive’ which is not the case with this window. Can I maybe set a fixed size and then .setStyleSheet (CSS) such that I don’t see the borders of the widget anymore?

Comment: @FrancescaMazzeo your first code, can I make sth like self.table_widget.resizeColumnsToContents() such that the cell/widget gets bigger if the name is longer? Just tried this line of code but the size of the cells seem to be fixed now. I also wanna make ID a bit smaller as there are only numbers inside of up to length 4.

Comment: Try version **2023-07-26 first code** this, i resized and blocked the auto-resize for the ID necklace and for the NAME column auto-resize

Comment: @Souleater Please consider that StackOverflow is not a helpdesk or code provider service. The OP has already been kind enough by providing the basic answer to your question, continuously asking for "can you make xyz" is taking advantage of their kindness and goes out of scope of the original question. Please take your time to study the documentation of QHeaderView (and related classes) and eventually create a *separate* question. Remember, StackOverflow is *not* a forum.

Comment: @FrancescaMazzeo No harm done. Please consider making the answer more descriptive (try to explain what you've done, as code only answers are generally frowned upon: their purpose is not just give the solution, but *educate*). Also, instead of proposing again most of the code, either add the differences with the original, or just keep one version: right now people will see an answer with *no explanation nor reference* for 3 very similar codes, they will not clearly see the differences between them and will have to find/understand them on their own. Please take your time to read [answer].

Comment: @musicamante Excuse me, I'm new on this platform, if there is a regulation where can I find it? Do you want me to leave only a single code in reference to the question (I think the first code since the green tick has been assigned to it)?

Comment: Yes I understand that, sorry for the inconvenience and thanks everyone! Didn't mean to take advantange of someone's kindness but I see your point, won't happen again.

Comment: @Dev.FrancescaMazzeo See the link in my previous comment, then you can visit the [help] and browse through some question with high (recent) votes and sufficient content to understand how answers are normally provided (consider looking for answers given by high ranking users too). You could leave any of the codes above, which one is up to you; you could use the first one, and then point out the differences from the others just by explaining it and showing the changed/removed/added lines, so that people will easily tell them apart.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).